# Changes made to ifcfg-wlan0 doesn't seem to make a difference

Tags: networking, rhel, wifi

I am running RHEL6 on my laptop. The wireless adapter configuration file `ifcfg-wlan0` didn't come by default under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. So I created it myself. The problem is, whatever changes I made to that file, it just won't make a difference. The wireless connection only drops immediately after I issue the command `/etc/init.d/network restart`, but will resume working fine after I manually choose a wireless network, and the changes I made won't apply(see the picture bellow). How could this happen?

[image]

Comment: `TYPE=ireless` - I believe it should be `TYPE=wireless`

Comment: @Serge that's exactly what I mean, i.e., whatever changes I made to the configuration file, it doesn't seem to have an effect to the real wireless interface, as you can see that the real IP address of the wlan0 shown in the picture is `192.168.1.255`, which obviously doesn't correspond with the one(`192.168.122.23`) I configured.